# django 3.2 : autoslugfield return None

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-3.8, slug

I installed autoslug on django3.2

my model:

```
from autoslug import AutoSlugField

class Courses(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_dynamic_path_course, null=True)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)

    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from=get_populate_from, null=True, blank=True, allow_unicode=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%d :  %s => ,  %s' % (self.id, self.title, self.slug)
```

function :

```
def get_populate_from(instance):
    return instance.title.replace(' ', '_')
```

my problem:

slug field is always None

Answer (score 0):

It's weird that it doesn't work. I would also think that it works the way you did it, but have you tried using lambda?

```
slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from=lambda instance: instance.title.replace(' ', '_'), null=True, blank=True, allow_unicode=True)
```

Another option would be to change the slugify function like this:

```
def custom_slugify(value):
    return value.replace(' ', '_')

slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', slugify=custom_slugify, null=True, blank=True, allow_unicode=True)
```

Comment: when i use lambda i get error :   cannot serialize function lamba

Comment: when i use slogify - slug is none

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like this:

```
from autoslug import AutoSlugField

    class Courses(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
        description = models.TextField(null=True)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_dynamic_path_course, null=True)
        price = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    
        slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')
    
        def slugify_function(self, content):
            return content.replace('_', '-').lower()
```